# Настройка NetBeans C++ 8.1

Tags: c++

Не могу начать программировать в среде *NetBeans 8.1 C++*. IDE запускается но не может найти компилятор *MinGW*.

Путь прописан:

```
PATH = ...;d:\MinGW32\bin;d:\MinGW32\msys\bin...
```

Что я должен сделать еще?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил вашу проблему (даже если это ваш ответ), то не поленитесь отметить ответ "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками" у ответов), чтобы он не висел в списке неотвеченных :)

Answer (score 1):

1. [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw.) у вас уже установлен, я правильно понимаю?
2. `...` в `PATH` вы чисто символически поставили или так и прописано в переменной?
3. Путь к *Minimal System (MSYS)*, кажется, по умолчанию должен иметь еще одну промежуточную директорию, что-то в духе: `D:\MinGW32\MSYS\1.0\bin` - проверьте правильно ли указан путь.
4. Необходимо также дописать в переменную реестра *Path* соответствующие пункту 3) пути. Для этого в windows (а судя по указанному пути вы ставите на windows) заходите в `Панель управления\Система и безопасность\Система\Дополнительные параметры системы\Переменные среды`, находите в разделе `Системные переменные` нужную вам перменную `Path` и дописываете (посредством кнопки `Изменить...`) в конец её пути для средств MinGW и MSYS из пункта 3) разделенные символом `;` (перед ними также поставьте `;`, чтобы отделить от того последнего пути в данной переменной, который был указан до вас)

---

Должно заработать, но если ничего не получится, то попробуйте воспроизвести в точности действия из этого [гайда](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/cpp-setup-instructions_ru.html).

Comment: Сам Netbeans не подхватит просто так с кондачка все пути. Посмотрите в `Сервис -> Параметры -> С/С++` если выбрана сборка, то все ли прописано и не выделено ли чего красным.

Answer (score 0):

Все работает после того как диспетчером задач убивается процесс mc.exe
(из Cygwin). Если этого не сделать IDE просто чего-то (незнаю чего) делает...
Причем как находит mc.exe и запускает не понятно - вимдимо находит 
в реестре ?...
Установлен Windows 8.1